# Most viewed post of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

Im using following code for getting most populer post with thumbnail.I have a custom post type taxonomy (Talks). Custom post types(video) have 6 category.

But my code not working. It just getting 1 post.But i have 10 post. How can i fix it?

```
    <?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'showposts' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',

    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Talks',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(
                371,
                372,
                373,
                374,
                375,
                376
            )
        )
    )
); // 
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()):
    $loop->the_post();
?>


                              <div class="box">
                               <a class="box-over" href="<?php
    the_permalink();
?>">
                                                <?php
    if (($video_thumbnail = get_video_thumbnail()) != null) {
        echo "<img src='" . $video_thumbnail . "' class='videowisetalksthumb' width='150' height='108' />";
    }
?>
                               </a>

                               <p class="videotitle"><a href="<?php
    the_permalink();
?>"><?php
    the_title();
?></a></p>        

                              </div>

                              <?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: First of all, you probably want to order by DESC, since you want the most popular on top, but that's an aside. How is post_views_count populated? Do you have more than one post with the post_views_count postmeta set? Note that this query will ONLY get posts if that is set.

Comment: 'post_views_count' maybe not populated but i need most viewed post.This value is important for me. How can list most viewed posts? Do you have any idea? I said, my code just listing one post. Thank for answer @Matthew Boynes

Comment: If you don't have a plugin currently populating the view count data, you'll need one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=popular. Best of luck!

Comment: I need do it without plugins. Thanks @Matthew Boynes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brain helped me..

I have installed already [WP-PostViews](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-postviews) Plugin

I just changed following line on my code and it worked.

Thanks for all answers and suggestion.

`'meta_key' => 'views'`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an existing plugin, then you could do something like this: [Post views without plugin](http://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/).

In the linked example, the author calls `setPostViews()` from single.php, but if you have a custom single template for your custom post type, then you'd add it there instead. This will increment your post view counts, which you can then query.

One last note: make sure to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after your display loop since you looped through a custom WP_Query. This is especially important if the code above is being rendered as a widget of some sort.

Comment: Hello @Brian, I think I explained it wrong. I do not need just the number of views.If you reviewed my code, I have already listed just one post? but why? I'm looking for an answer to it. Thanks for all!

Comment: There is a missing comma after `'order' => 'DESC'` that would affect the `$args` passed to WP_Query. You might also verify that the terms specified in `'tax_query'` are not inadvertently filtering your results -- try removing the `'tax_query'` and seeing if that increases the number of results you get.

Comment: Hello Brian, I made ​​a mistake while editing code (a missing comma after 'order' => 'DESC') thanks, but still just one post listing ( 'tax_query' removed ).

Comment: All I can guess is that there is only a single post that has a custom key of `'post_views_count'`, or that there is only a single post matching that `'post_type'`. Try removing the `'meta_key'` filter first, and if that doesn't work, remove `'post_type'`...working your way back to super simple to see where the query is breaking down.

Comment: When i remove 'meta_key' it worked but listing recent post.

Comment: I think that's the issue then -- you'll need to generate more views on your video posts so that they are assigned custom meta for `'post_views_count'`. If your theme/functions doesn't already have some type of view increment script, then you can refer to the one I mentioned above in my answer.

Comment: I generate more views other post but not changed still same post listing,so 'post_views_count' not working..@brain i could not use this function (your answer) to my query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7807/discussion-between-brian-and-genxer)